# SyntaxError at phyton script

Tags: ssl-certificate, python, syntax

I try to run an python script but I get errors.

```
File "./ics2owncloud.py", line 41
r = requests.put('%s/%s.ics' % (base_url, uid) verify=False),
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How must i add the `verify=false` in this script part?

[This](https://gist.github.com/guddl/807589d3f460df2dc020e32a50c36f9d) is the original.
With this I get this error message:

> SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

With this modified script only the Syntax error.

What is wrong?

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this on your own?

Comment: @gf_ I didn't solve this. I ask how can I add the verify=false string to this code?

Comment: I know. I've asked for your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
r = requests.put('%s/%s.ics' % (base_url, uid), verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks that is solved. But the next error 'File "./ics2owncloud.py", line 42
    data=cal.to_ical(),
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent'

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Now I got this message '/ics2owncloud$ ./ics2owncloud.sh                                File "./ics2owncloud.py", line 42
    data=cal.to_ical(),
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent'

Comment: Look here: '  r = requests.put('%s/%s.ics' % (base_url, uid), verify=False)
                     data=cal.to_ical(),
                     auth=(username, password),
                     headers={'content-type':'text/calendar; charset=UTF-8'}'